# Received odd RVM error in workspace, now rails commands aren't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, ruby-on-rails-5, cloud9

I just logged into my Ubuntu workspace on Cloud9. Upon logging in I saw an error.

```
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does
that too, you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore
/home/ubuntu/workspace/Simutronix/Gemfile'. To ignore the warning for
all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.
```

Which I've not seen before and wasn't occurring when I last used the workspace. I then attempted to run the Rails server.

```
rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
```

I got an error message back.

```
bash: rails: command not found
```

I then tried to run `bundle install` which also came back with `command not found`.

`ruby -v` returns `ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]`.

What's likely to have happened to cause this to happen in between logins and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Ubuntu can't find your Rails installation. Make sure you have Rails installed on your workspace by typing:

```
rails -v
```

If it is properly installed, It should return something like

```
Rails 5.0.2
```

(depending upon your Rails version.)

If you don't have Rails installed, you can install it by typing

```
gem install rails
```

You can append `--no-doc` to the above command if you don't want it to install documentation, thereby speeding up the installation process (That's totally up to you, though. It won't affect your installation in any other way. I promise!)

If this doesn't solve your problem, please update your answer with your Gemfile.

Comment: Hhhmmmm. It's all working now. Forgot that `bundle` is a subset command of rails not of ruby. Do you know why this might have happened? Rails used to periodically delete itself and the installation mess up on my old server too, but I thought it had stopped happening since I moved to Cloud9. I'm also confused why the error mentioned Heroku doing something, since I don't see why an RVM error would mention my production platform that way!

Comment: After you installed RVM, did you add the command starting with ```source``` ? BTW, ```bundler``` is a gem

Comment: I haven't done anything since I closed down my Cloud9 workspace last night. I don't remember using that command before... could that be to do with the problem?

Comment: Let me get this straight. Do RVM and Ruby remain installed whenever you reopen your workspace?

Comment: Yes. They always have before, and both RVM and Ruby seemed to be there this time. I've always had access to Rails when logging back in before too, since I moved to Cloud9.

Comment: Restart your workspace, check if rails is installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139534/discussion-between-faraaz-ahmad-and-rails-kiddie).

Answer (score 0):

Likely the Ruby version defined in your Gemfile and/or `.ruby-version` changed, which means you will have to install bundler and bundle the gems again. Running this should solve the issue:

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
```